# Array Algorithm

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have a project to create a milestone chart. The problem at hand is that the chart uses an array with empty values, i need to fill in the blanks if the user doesn't enter value for them, and these values must incremental and within range of original milestone values.for example, I have a project that runs for several months, and the user enters a milestone for some months while the rest are empty. I need to enter a value for each empty month, and it must be within the values of previously entered months. So far i'm failing at that because the values would be correct up to certain point then fails.
here is the array: (Note: the last value of the array will always be 100)

```js
var myarray = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100];

function plotMilestones(arr) {
  arr = Object.keys(arr).map(function(key) {
    if (!arr.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return arr[key];
    }
  });

  if (arr[arr.length - 1] === 0) {
    arr.splice(arr.length - 1, 0, 100);
  }
  var array = [];
  var milestone = 0;
  var oldMilestone = 0;
  var months = 0;
  var index = 0;
  var monthCount = 0;
  var result = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var value = arr[i];

    if (value === 0) {
      array.push(value);
      months++;
    } else if (value > 0 && oldMilestone == 0) {
      if (months > 0) {
        milestone = value;
        oldMilestone = arr[0];
        monthCount = index + months;
        for (index = firstZero(array); index < months; index++) {
          result = milestone / (months) + oldMilestone;
          array.splice(index, 1, result);
          months--;
        }
      }


      oldMilestone = milestone;
      milestone = 0;
    } else if (value > 0 && oldMilestone > 0) {
      if (months > 0) {
        oldMilestone = array[firstZero(array) - 1];
        milestone = value;
        monthCount = index + months;
        for (index = firstZero(array); index <= monthCount; index++) {
          result = milestone / (months) + oldMilestone;
          array.splice(index, 1, result);
          months--;
        }

        array.push(milestone);

        oldMilestone = milestone;
        milestone = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  return array;
}

function firstZero(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === 0)
      return i;
  }
}

let x = plotMilestones(myarray);
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Should we assume that it would just fall back from 60 to 0 at the end?  And are you looking for a steady change in between or something random?  (A steady change should be easy.)

Comment: Specify Input parameter and expected output result.

Comment: no It shouldn't because the last value of the array will always be 100, so there is always something to calculate. And yes, it should be steady. I thought of linear regression, but i don't think it applies here. @ScottSauyet

Comment: Yes please put some test cases in with expected results for each including at least one for the same index in the array or specify why it cannot be used.  We seek clarity in your question here.

Comment: @DipakTelangre the input is the array i showed above, and the output should be something like this

```[1,2,3,5,7,8,(10),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,(30),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,(60),0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]```

you see how it incremented from 1 to 10 (user entered value), it should like this all the way in the array. so after 30, should 31, 32 and so on (depends on the two values provided)

Comment: "the last value of the array will always be 100"  Please update your question with that, right now it has "last" as 0.  EDIT rather than just comment to make the actual question clear.

Comment: I made a snippet of your code.  I has issues i.e.""Uncaught ReferenceError: firstZero is not defined"" when ran

Comment: Please clarify what is meant by ",(30),...{60) " that is not valid in your array

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I have updated the code to include firstZero(). I meant by (30) that they are the user entered value.

Comment: I do not see here how any valid array passed as a parameter can be set to determine the user entered value.  Is there some what that is determined?  or is this supposed to be "any non-0 value"?

Comment: it supposed be any non-0 value @MarkSchultheiss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possibility, based on the assumption that you start at 0 and end at 100:

```js
const interpolate = milestones => {
  const indices = [0, ...Object .keys (milestones) .filter (i => milestones [i] > 0)] 
    .map (Number)

  return milestones .map ((_, i) => {
    if (i == 0) {return milestones [0]}
    const b = indices .findIndex (idx => idx >= i), a = b - 1
    const c = indices [a], d = indices [b]
    const x = milestones [c], y = milestones [d]
    return Math.round((y - x) * (i - c) / (d - c) + x)
  })
}

const milestones = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100]

console .log (
  interpolate (milestones)
)
```

We start by collecting the relevant milestones, including the first one, with the assumption that we have already added `100` to the end.  This gives us `[0,6,18,31,41]`, which are the indices of `[0, 10, 30, 60, 100]` in the input.  We use these indices to calculate the results by mapping over our list, ignoring the value but paying attention to the index:

Let's say we've hit index `25`.  We find the index of first of the relevant milestone greater than 25 (which is 31), at index 3, so `b` is `3`, and hence `a` is `2`, and we set `c` and `d` to those milestone indices, `18` and `31`.  We set `x` and `y` to the actual milestone values at those indices, `30` and `60`.  Then we perform a linear interpolation ( `(60 - 30) * (25 - 18) / (31 - 18) + 30`) on those to get the value `46.15384615384615`, which I round to 46.  Obviously you can skip the rounding, or round to one decimal, or whatever you choose.

Comment: Thank you Scott. You literally saved the day. Also thank you for the explaination because I’m interested in this type of algorithms

Comment: There's not much to the algorithm.  The greatest work is just to find the relevant indices.  After that, it's simple linear interpolation. (If `t` ranges between `x` and `y` while `s` ranges between `a` and `b`, then `t(s) = x + (y - x) * (s - a) / (b - a)`.)